# Question regarding sets and events

Tags: probability, statistics

Say we have 3 sets $A,B$ and $C$ and

$A\cap C =\varnothing$

$B\cap C = \varnothing$

$S\setminus A = B$

where $S$ is the sample space.

The question is whether $\{A,B\}$ is an event space or not. I am not able to figure out how to solve this, do i make a venn diagram or something? How would that look like cause I don't get how $S\setminus A = B$ part will work in that.

Comment: If S\A= B then $S= A\cup B$ so C is disjoint from S.

Comment: @user247327 thanks, that would mean that {A,B} as an event space right?

Comment: @sgman No, the set $\{A,B\}$ should - as event space - at least contain $S$ and $\varnothing$, which is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

Formally an [event space](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Event_Space) is a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal A$ with $\mathcal A\subseteq\wp(S)$ where $S$ denotes the [sample space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_space).

That means that also $\varnothing$ and $S$ must be elements of $\mathcal A$.

This is not guaranteed by the data.

Only in the special cases $\langle A,B\rangle=\langle\varnothing, S\rangle$ and  $\langle A,B\rangle=\langle S,\varnothing\rangle$ the set $\{A,B\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.